# VSS to TFS Migration - Persist User on check-in actions

Tags: tfs, migration, visual-sourcesafe, tfs-migration, vssconverter

I am using the VSSConveter.exe tool to import from VSS6 (using 2005 ide) to TFS2008.
I have run analyze (no errors) and migrate WITH a user mapping file (containg the vss/domain user mappings)

I would like to persist in tfs the check-in user of the file, currently the check-in user for all versions of file shows as admin (the account im running the import with), the origional check-in user is appended to the check-in comment. For example:-

TestFile.aspx in VSS

- Check in ver: 1 - User:Adam - Comment:TEST1
- Check in ver: 2 - User:James - Comment:TEST2
- Check in ver: 3 - User:Joel - Comment:TEST2

After import into TFS

- Check in ver: 1 - User:mydomain\Admin - Comment:TEST1 (Commited by Adam)
- Check in ver: 2 - User:mydomain\Admin - Comment:TEST2 (Commited by James)
- Check in ver: 3 - User:mydomain\Admin - Comment:TEST2 (Commited by Joel)

In TFS I want the user to show as the correct domain user as configured in my user mapping file.

Is this possible, or is this just how the VSSConverter program works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just how it works.

The import is performed through the API which calculates the checkin time and user automatically to prevent people supplying their own values which could easily mess up history.  Because there's no way to override these values the import tags both the original date and user via comments on the checkin.

Edit: The use of a usermapping file will allow the import process to replace VSS usernames with correct TFS usernames (as discussed in the comments)

Comment: Thanks Richard, can you tell me what the usermapping file is actually used for. For example in the comments it has the old username (Adam), not the mapped username (mydomain\adam.jenkin). I cannot see were it has done any user mapping.

Comment: VSS usernames are the VSS accounts created via the VSSAdmin tool and they don't have a direct relation to AD names.  TFS works with AD so it needs to know how the VSS names map to AD names.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253175%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: I have created a user mapping file for my import, but cannot see were it has done any mapping of the vss users to the ad users.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the UserMap.xml was ignored unless you add an xml node to the migration settings XML file
here is the top part of my file to show where it goes.
Is there a document showing the full schema of migration mapping XML file?

```
<SourceControlConverter>
    <ConverterSpecificSetting>
        <Source name="VSS">
            <SQL Server="W00027"></SQL>
            <VSSDatabase name="D:\Program Files\SourceSafe"></VSSDatabase>
            <UserMap name="D:\Program Files\SourceSafe\Conversions\UserMap.xml" />
        </Source>
...
```